# Azure Data Factory reading Blob folder dealing with random characters

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to define a dataset that is has a file path of
`awsomedata/1992-12-25{random characters}MT/users.json`

I am unsure of how to use the expression language fully. I have figured out the following
`@startsWith( pipeline().parameters.filepath(),concat('awsomedata/',formatDateTime(utcnow('d'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')), @pipeline().parameters.filePath)`

The dataset will change dynamically, I am trying to tell it to look at the file each trigger to determine the schema.

Comment: Hi, as you mentioned random characters in the middle of the file path, can you please confirm if the remaining part is always the same every time? like the characters 'awsomedata/1992-12-25' and characters 'MT/users.json' are constant?

Comment: I am working on an alternative approach. Instead of trying to pull the folder out, I'm pulling the file name and the filepath from the trigger (blob create). I think it is almost there, I found that triggerBody().folderPath in the trigger parameters, but that includes the container. What I am currently trying to do is replace that with nothing to accept the whole folder path without needing to try and figure out the above-complicated question.